# Why doesn't Spring throw DataAccessException in the event that Hibernate throws ObjectNotFoundException?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, exception

Why doesn't [Spring 3.0.4](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/) [`HibernateTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.4/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate/HibernateTemplate.html) method [`load()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.4/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate/HibernateTemplate.html#load%28java.lang.Object,%20java.io.Serializable%29) throw  [`DataAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.4/api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html) or more specifically, [`ObjectRetrievalFailureException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.4/api/org/springframework/orm/ObjectRetrievalFailureException.html), in the event that [Hibernate 3.3.2GA](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/) throws [`ObjectNotFoundException`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/ObjectNotFoundException.html)?

```
2010-12-15 13:16:03,939 133247782 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO  org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener - Error performing load command
org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.db.spgit.abstrack.model.ConsUsCustomMark#78445AAD8]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl$1.handleEntityNotFound(SessionFactoryImpl.java:375) ~[hibernate-3.2.1.ga.jar:3.2.1.ga]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:145) ~[hibernate-3.2.1.ga.jar:3.2.1.ga]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:179) ~[hibernate-3.2.1.ga.jar:3.2.1.ga]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:103) ~[hibernate-3.2.1.ga.jar:3.2.1.ga]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:878) [hibernate-3.2.1.ga.jar:3.2.1.ga]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:795) [hibernate-3.2.1.ga.jar:3.2.1.ga]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:788) [hibernate-3.2.1.ga.jar:3.2.1.ga]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$3.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:558) [spring-orm-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406) [spring-orm-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374) [spring-orm-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.load(HibernateTemplate.java:551) [spring-orm-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.load(HibernateTemplate.java:545) [spring-orm-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception is being *logged*, not necessarily thrown. What you see there is a log to info level of the exception stack trace, done by hibernate. If you look at the source code of DefaultLoadEventListener(line 134 in my version of the source) you will notice that it logs the exception and then rethrows.

All we're seeing here is a log of the exception stack trace - there is no evidence here that spring is not transforming the exception.

Comment: Michael, you are right!  I had not noticed that it was Hibernate that had generated this log message.  I misinterpreted the log entry to mean that Spring had not translated the exception when in fact, it had.  The fact that the application hadn't propagated this exception any higher up the stack should have clued me in that Spring was correctly handling this exception.

Answer (score 0):

The `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException()` method does check to see if the exception is `net.sf.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException`.  This means that it should be throwing an `UncategorizedDataAccessException`.

I do not know if this is a design decision or an oversite (i.e. a bug in spring).

Comment: Spring translates `ObjectNotFoundException` to `ObjectRetrievalFailureException`.